# How to setup "dotnet tool install" to use a local nexus mirror?

Tags: .net-core

When I use :
`dotnet tool install`

I can see it's downloading from https://api.nuget.org

```
   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-sonarscanner/index.json
   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-sonarscanner/index.json 490ms
   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-sonarscanner/4.8.0/dotnet-sonarscanner.4.8.0.nupkg
   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dotnet-sonarscanner/4.8.0/dotnet-sonarscanner.4.8.0.nupkg 11ms
```

How can I setup dotnet tool install to use a local nexus mirror repository ?

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work. It uses your set up nuget sources. What issues are you experiencing? If you list the nuget sources with `dotnet nuget list source`, what does it say? Does it list the repository in question?

E.g. mine lists:

```
C:\> dotnet nuget list source
Registered Sources:
  1.  CompanyRepo [Enabled]
      https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/_packaging/repo/nuget/v3/index.json
  2.  LocalRepo [Enabled]
      C:\Users\erik\LocalRepo
  3.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  4.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Enabled]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

If your nexus mirror is not listed there, you should be able to add it with `dotnet nuget add source`.

Comment: Thanks for the "list source" command, it may be useful, I'm quite new to dotnet core. I'm closing this question since it's a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974776/how-to-build-this-project-on-a-jenkins-agent