# How to build this project on a jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins, .net-core

I'm trying to create a jenkins agent able to build dotnet core projects using only our local mirror (no connexion to the internet allowed).

I've read various articles on this topic, and I'm using a NuGet.config like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear /> <!-- ensure only the sources defined below are used -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://si-devops-mirror.mycomp.fr/repository/nuget.org/" protocolVersion="2" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This file is in ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config (please tell me if this is wrong).

But when I do `dotnet restore`, it tries to reach https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json :

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Impossible de charger l'index de service pour la source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
```

Is there a way to avoid any attempt to reach something on the internet ?

Comment: You should add custom nuget source on your build agent

Comment: What I can see in the doc is : "source URL for nuget.org is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" and I've tried to add a custom nuget source by specifying : "<add key="nuget.org" value="https://si-devops-mirror.mycomp.fr/repository/nuget.org/" protocolVersion="2" />". Can you tell me what I did wrong please ?

Comment: You should use different name for custom source, and manage auth key (if it exists)

Comment: What I did is : I didn't change anything in my NuGet.Config, I explicitly passed the NuGet.Config path to restore "dotnet restore --configfile ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config" and nothing else, and it worked. Do you know why it wasn't picking the standard located NuGet.Config ? or is it random ?